# unsupported major minor version 51.0 error in ubuntu

Tags: java

i am trying to set up hadoop single node cluster environment in ubuntu. While giving hadoop version command i am getting the unsupported major minor version error 51.0 .I have checked that both versions (JAVAC and JAVA) are same as jdk1.6.0_35 and set java_home to usr/lib/java/jdk1.6.0_35

I am very new to this and dont know how to proceed.Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.Thanks in advance !

Comment: What does `echo $JAVA_HOME` show you?  We need to verify the version of Java which is actually _running_ on Ubuntu.

Comment: it shows me usr/lib/java/jdk1.6.0_35

Comment: Class file version 51 requires Java 7.